# How did the word Shiur acquire its meaning of lesson?

Tags: commentaries, language

I found out that the word שִׁעוּר/שיעור means measure or amount, and from here it derives it's meaning of rate, frequency and occurance. But how come this word also carries the meaning of lesson/teaching?

Or as the balashon [website](http://www.balashon.com/2010/07/shiur-and-shaar.html) puts it: "a set measure of learning"